# AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'left'

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, matplotlib

I tried to work on the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625535/format-pd-interval-categories-when-plotting?noredirect=1#comment94111511_53625535)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,23,56,78,3,3,5,7,9,12]

new_list = pd.Series(my_list)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Range1':new_list.value_counts().index, 'Range2':new_list.value_counts().values})

df1.sort_values(by=["Range1"],inplace=True)

df2 = df1.groupby(pd.cut(df1["Range1"], [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,df1['Range1'].max()])).sum()

objects = df2['Range2'].index

y_pos = np.arange(len(df2['Range2'].index))


l = df2.index.categories.left.map("{:02d}".format)
r = df2.index.categories.right.map("{:02d}".format)

plt.bar(range(len(df2)), df2['Range2'].values, tick_label='('+l+', '+r+']')
plt.xticks(fontsize=6)

plt.show()
```

on Python 2.7 but getting the below error message:

```
 l = df1_cut.index.categories.left.map("{:02d}".format)
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'left'
```

Not getting how to resolve and make it work?

Comment: What does `pd.__version__` show?

Comment: please describe what your goal is

Comment: @coldspeed pd.__version__ = 0.18.1, np.__version__ = 1.14.5, matplotlib version = 2.1.2

Comment: Can you please update to 0.23?

Comment: The code you posted is assuming that `cut` is backed by an `IntervalIndex`, which was not introduced until version 0.20.0.

Comment: @coldspeed Can the solution be made to work with existing versions? As I can't upgrade the version.

Comment: Hmm, can't say. I don't have v0.18 on my machine :(

Comment: @coldspeed Let me try and get back to you.