# What does it mean to have a TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'?

Tags: python, pandas, function, jupyter-notebook, distribution

I made this function to find the distribution of all the columns in my pandas dataframe and it works when I have each individual line in separate cells, but when I put it into this one function I get the error message

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'
```

I'm relatively new to coding so I don't know what that means or how to fix it. Please help! thank you

```
def function():
    for x in range(df.shape[1]):
        columns = df.columns
        if len(df[columns[x]].unique()) > 10:
            samp = pd.qcut(df[columns[x]], 4)
            bins = samp.unique
            sampdf = pd.DataFrame(samp)
            ex1 = sampdf.groupby(columns[x]).agg({columns[x]:'count'})
            ex2 = ex1.reset_index(drop=True)`
        else:
            samp = df[columns[x]]
            sampdf = pd.DataFrame(samp)
            ex1 = sampdf.groupby(columns[x]).agg({columns[x]:'count'})
            
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    plt.bar(ex1.index, ex1[columns[x]], color= 'purple')
    plt.ylabel('Customers')
    plt.xlabel(columns[x])
    plt.title('Distribution of ' + columns[x])
    plt.show()
```

The Traceback was:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-c0b3cafe2087> in <module>
----> 1 function1()

<ipython-input-27-bcfb6d749f86> in function1()
     15 
     16         plt.style.use('ggplot')
---> 17         plt.bar(ex1.index, ex1[columns[0]], color= 'purple')
     18         plt.ylabel('Customers')
     19         plt.xlabel(columns[0])

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in bar(x, height, width, bottom, align, data, **kwargs)
   2485         x, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, *, align='center',
   2486         data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2487     return gca().bar(
   2488         x, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, align=align,
   2489         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1436     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1437         if data is None:
-> 1438             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1439 
   1440         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in bar(self, x, height, width, bottom, align, **kwargs)
   2492             elif orientation == 'horizontal':
   2493                 r.sticky_edges.x.append(l)
-> 2494             self.add_patch(r)
   2495             patches.append(r)
   2496 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in add_patch(self, p)
   2031         if p.get_clip_path() is None:
   2032             p.set_clip_path(self.patch)
-> 2033         self._update_patch_limits(p)
   2034         self.patches.append(p)
   2035         p._remove_method = self.patches.remove

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _update_patch_limits(self, patch)
   2051         vertices = patch.get_path().vertices
   2052         if vertices.size > 0:
-> 2053             xys = patch.get_patch_transform().transform(vertices)
   2054             if patch.get_data_transform() != self.transData:
   2055                 patch_to_data = (patch.get_data_transform() -

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py in get_patch_transform(self)
    790 
    791     def get_patch_transform(self):
--> 792         self._update_patch_transform()
    793         return self._rect_transform
    794 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py in _update_patch_transform(self)
    769         """
    770         x0, y0, x1, y1 = self._convert_units()
--> 771         bbox = transforms.Bbox.from_extents(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    772         rot_trans = transforms.Affine2D()
    773         rot_trans.rotate_deg_around(x0, y0, self.angle)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py in from_extents(*args)
    820         The *y*-axis increases upwards.
    821         """
--> 822         return Bbox(np.reshape(args, (2, 2)))
    823 
    824     def __format__(self, fmt):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py in __init__(self, points, **kwargs)
    772         """
    773         BboxBase.__init__(self, **kwargs)
--> 774         points = np.asarray(points, float)
    775         if points.shape != (2, 2):
    776             raise ValueError('Bbox points must be of the form '

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'
```

Comment: Could you include the entire stacktrace? Note. Seems a line of your code is trying to pass  a `pandas` object to `float()` which only accepts `strings` and `int`

Comment: @PacketLoss I'm sorry I'm new to this what is a stacktrace?

Comment: When Python throws an error, it prints a stacktrace which includes your error. You need to include the entire stacktrace in your question as the partial one you have included misses vital information, such as the line number the error occured on. https://realpython.com/python-traceback/

Comment: @PacketLoss okay thank you for explaining! I edited the post and included the stacktrace

Comment: Could you also include an example of the input `dataframe`?

Comment: Ah, seems like the issue is due to `matplotlib` not being able to plot `category` dtypes. The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53619985/7942856) may help resolve your issue.

Comment: @PacketLoss ah okay thank you so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: float() argument must be a string or a number,not 'pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619746/python-float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-pandas)